# Why is Wikipedia taking up so much RAM on Ubuntu (with Google Chrome) and how can I reduce it?

Tags: google-chrome, performance, ram, websites, optimization

My laptop with 16GB of RAM keeps running out of RAM and the top 10 processes chewing up the RAM are always from Google Chrome tabs, some which are using 900MB of RAM:

[image]

Opening Google Chrome's own task manager and organizing from largest to smallest RAM users, we see that Wikipedia is what is chewing up all the RAM, often taking up 3 times more RAM than gmail, for example.

[image]

Also the Wikipedia pages taking up the most RAM, are the ones that have been open for the longest.

I am using the extension app called "[The Great Suspender](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-great-suspender/klbibkeccnjlkjkiokjodocebajanakg?hl=en)" which suspends tabs when they haven't been used for a while, and that's why there's so many tabs showing up in the Chrome Task Manager whose names start with "Extension". These tabs whose names start with "Extension" do not take up any RAM, as you can see in the Chrome Task Manager screenshot.

Some of the Wikipedia pages have been open for several days, and I haven't actively done anything such as "viewing" those pages at all during this time, so they should be suspended by The Great Suspender extension, just like everything else was. However Wikipedia pages seem not to get suspended like this so maybe those pages are automatically refreshing every 1 hour or so, or maybe Wikipedia is collecting some of my data.

1) I wonder if anyone knows why Wikipedia is taking up so much RAM, and not getting suspended like the rest of the tabs do.
2) I wonder what to do to fix this problem apart from closing the tabs and re-opening them. The great suspender doesn't work. I can use the extension "one tab" which combines all tabs into one tab which has links to the rest (hence using no RAM), but I don't want to do that.

Comment: Sorry that the screenshots came out pixelated. It's the best I could do. The first image just organizes the tasks from largest to smallest RAM and the top 10 are from Google Chrome. The second image is Chrome's own task manager which shows that the top 10 most RAM-demanding tabs are all Wikipedia.

Comment: if you're using Chrome 70 you need to update it to 71 version it has lots of fixes.

Comment: Seems I have Chrome 56... does Chrome not update itself automatically?

Comment: It depends how did you install it.

Comment: I upgraded to version 71 shortly after you suggested it. It did not help at all, in fact those Wikipedia pages that were taking up 900MB of RAM, are now taking up 1.4GB of RAM.